# Target _blank for rich text prismic on NextJs

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css, prismic.io, tailwind-in-js

I have a RichText with two files (terms and conditions) in prismic that I want to open in new tab bit there's no option like target _blank or something like that in prismic, I'm using NextJs with Tailwind CSS

Answer (score 1):

in the content model, there is an option for allows target blank opt. However, you still need to build out the function yourself.

[image]